# In English, what does "Set X to Y" mean?

Tags: meaning

In English, what does "Set X to Y" mean?
Does it mean, X = Y?
Or does it mean, Y = X?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301770/set-something-a-setting-variable-piece-of-configuration-to-at-for-a-specific

Answer (score 2):

Doing a search for the phrase "set a value to something," as well as going over the list of dictionary definitions for the verb "set," both failed to turn up a clear, concise definition which is generally applicable. So, instead I'll provide an *example*:

> If you **set x to y**, the value of **x** becomes what the value of **y** was at the time the 'setting' happened.

Of the two alternatives you proposed, it means the same as

> X = Y

So, if **x is 4**, **y is 25**, and you **set x to y**, then **x becomes 25** while y stays the same as it was (i.e. still 25).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question, Quack E. Duck.  Like you, I was under the impression that the first choice (X=Y) should be correct, but some technical books and documentations seem to mean the 2nd choice (Y=X). And that is why I am not sure which one is correct.

Comment: @ForgivnChildOf-Gd That is very interesting, and I have never heard that usage. If you can find a specific example, it would definitely be worth including in your question.  One possibility that comes to mind is that your source may have said "*assign* x to y" to mean "make y become what x was."  I believe that if you use "assign," the relationship is indeed ambiguous which value is being changed. But, to the best of my understanding, there is no such ambiguity with "set."